# Css border bottom stay fixed for both two digits and one digits

Tags: html, css

Here is the html code

```
<div>
   <div class="fractop"><span>11</span></div>
   <div class="fracbottom">2</div>
</div>

<div>
   <div class="fractop"><span>5</span></div>
   <div class="fracbottom">2</div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code

```
<style>
   .fractop{
       border-bottom:solid black 0px; 
       display:inline-block; 
       float:left;
       margin-top:20px; 
       text-align:center; 
       width:100%;
   }
   .fracbottom{ 
       display:inline-block;
       clear:left; 
       float:left; 
       width:100%; 
       text-align:center;
   }
   .fractop span{
       border-bottom:solid black 3px; 
    }

</style>
```

I need to  make the "divide by" line for fractions stay fixed for 2 digits. It need not become longer or shorter dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `.fractop span` to this

```
.fractop span{
   border-bottom:solid black 3px; 
   width: 17px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

I have a working demo in this fiddle - put an HR between your two numbers, then style it as a line - does as you prescribe. I also added some inline styling to the parent div to help. You can easily move that to it's own css class though.

http://jsfiddle.net/rrp46faj/2/

```
<div style="width:20px !important;"><div class="fractop"><span>11</span></div>
    <hr>
<div class="fracbottom">2</div>
</div>

<div style="width:20px;"><div class="fractop"><span>5</span></div>
    <hr>
<div class="fracbottom">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `.score_middle`?

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply @remy. If i remove this line, both divide by line is not fixed. I need to  "divide by" line for fractions stay fixed for all digits.

Comment: Edited and updated, this should solve your problem. Check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

while your approach isn't the best and you're over complicating things, to give you an answer within that approach, change your CSS to this:

```
.fractop{border-bottom:solid black 0px; display:block; margin-top:20px; text-align:center; width:15px; margin:0; padding:0 3px;border-bottom:solid black 3px;}
.fracbottom{ display:block; margin-top:20px; text-align:center; width:15px; margin:0; padding:0 3px;}
```

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8sgh4sbs/) and change it at will

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  `&#8260`

Example : `<div class="fractop">4.0000 &#8260; 5.3456</div>`

You can find more details here http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-math.htm

You can also see [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)